# I want to insert the image in between the content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, insert

I am beginner in ruby on rails. I am developing a blog where I can write articles.
 **Article** table has **title**, **content** and **image** columns.

***Article Model***

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base

has_attached_file :image, styles: { medium: "300x300>", thumb: "100x100>" }
validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/

end
```

***Articles Controller***

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController

def index
    @articles = Article.all.order("created_at DESC")
end

def new
    @article = Article.new
end

def create
    @article = Article.new article_params
    if @article.save
        redirect_to articles_path
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end

def edit
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
end

def update
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    if @article.update article_params
        redirect_to articles_path
    else
        render 'edit'
    end
end


private

def article_params
    params.require(:article).permit(:title, :content, :image)
end

end
```

***Articles#new***

```
<%= form_for @article, html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :title, placeholder: "Title" %><br /><br />
  <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "Content" %><br /><br />
  <%= f.file_field :image %><br /><br />
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

I am using "paperclip gem" for uploading images.
 I am able to upload and display the image corresponding to the article.
What I need is I want to display the image in between the content of the article whereever I needed(like in stackoverflow). Please help me on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: StackOverflow uses mark down - you may need to use something like that for content, you will have to use markdown parser gem

Comment: Wow.. Really a big thanks for u. You better post this in answer. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

StackOverflow uses Markdown for its content.

You can use gem like [RedCarpet](https://github.com/vmg/redcarpet) to parse mark down, and render content similar to StackOverflow.

There is a Rails Casts video on this topic - [Ruby on Rails - Railscasts #272 Markdown With Redcarpet](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vPW6t-r0xzM)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99328/discussion-between-akash-pinnaka-and-wand-maker).

Answer (score 2):

For images, you can try an rich editor like CKeditor, hooked with Paperclip/Carrierwave.
Usually it'll use a separate model to store images.
You'll upload images through CKeditor and it'll insert the image in content.

Comment: Is that a tool to embed in the browser page?

Comment: Yes, CKeditor is a javascript based text editor. You can embed it on any web page.